# Thinking Sphinx - can't get exact match first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have quite simple thinking sphinx setup:

Indeces:

```
indexes first_name, :sortable => true  
indexes last_name, :sortable => true  
indexes family_name, :sortable => true  
indexes born_date, :sortable => true  
indexes death_date, :sortable => true
```

There are some other related models in it but thats not the case.

Thats the riddle I use:

```
Riddle::Query.escape( URI.decode(params[:search]) ),
       :star => true,
       :per_page => params[:per_page],
       :page => params[:page],
       :ranker => :sph04,
       :match_mode => :phrase,
       :order => ('death_date DESC')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is exact matches first on the list. 
Now when I search for "Anna" I get all mixed like "Hanna", "Anna-Lisa" before "Anna". 
It's even worst when I remove 'order'. I've tried several rankers and mach modes with no luck. 
It would be perfect if I get exact mach on top and sorted by other attribute (date), and other matches after it, also sorted by date.

Only solution that came to my head now is sort by result length (shorter is closer to exact match), but maybe there is some better solution?

Any clues how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    :order => ('death_date DESC')
> ```

Well that will completely ignore the 'weight', and only order by that attribute.

Sorting by particular value, AND by weight, is hard. 
Can possibly look at some sort of hybrid, segment based system
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/06/27/doing-time-segments-geodistance-searches-and-overrides-in-sphinxql/

> I get all mixed like "Hanna",

if you match that, sounds like you have `enable_star` set to 0 somehow. And/or `expand_keywords` (these are sphinx config options, dont know how the translate into thinkingSphinx. )

.. turning these off, should allow only 'while word matches'.

In which case, should then get better results. Beyond that, even though SPH04 is meant to promote 'exact field' matches, I dont find it works all that well. Can play with custom rankers.

Or 
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=1923
has some methods to manipulate the queries a bit, to promote results.